# Program/extension/userscript software to find large videos in Google+

Tags: google-apps

https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/6558?hl=en says:

> Google+ Photos: Only photos over 2048 x 2048 pixels and videos longer
>   than 15 minutes count towards your storage limit.

In order to make space in my account, I'd like to list all my videos longer than 15 minutes in my Google+ Photo account.

I'm therefore looking for a program/extension/userscript software to my +15-minute videos in Google+. (if possible free and supporting Windows 7).

Comment: Do you want it to analyze your online Google account or would analyzing your GoogleDrive Folder *on your computer* be acceptable?

Comment: Online Google account if possible. But I'm curious: have Google+ photos/videos have their own folder in Gdrive?

Comment: oh hmm I didn't read that very well - I was thinking you were saying photos/videos in GDrive rather than Google+. I don't actually know - would be handy in some ways if so.

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest I've got to solving the same problem I had.

Ref: http://muzso.hu/2012/02/26/list-photos-and-videos-from-picasa-web-albums-google-that-are-over-a-specified-width-heig

> The attached Python script helps you with this. It should be run from
>   the commandline with a Picasa Web Ablums or Google+ username as its
>   first parameter and it'll list all (public) photos and videos that are
>   over the limit for the unlimited storage pool. At the time of writing
>   the limit is 2048 pixels for photographs and 15 minutes for videos for
>   Google+ users and these are the defaults for the script as well (but
>   you can specify your own limits on the commandline as second and third
>   arguments).
>
> Actually you can use the optional 2nd and 3rd arguments (with a value
>   of zero) to list all photos and videos (it'll print their dimensions
>   and sizes too) in a Picasa Web Albums or Google+ account. Might come
>   handy if you want a full listing of all your (public) uploads.

Link to Code: http://muzso.hu/dfiles/public/google_photos_over_limit.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#
# This script will go through all the public photos and videos of the specified
# PicasaWeb or Google+ user and list those that fall into the limited category
# (ie. for photos: width or height is over 2048 pixels
#      for videos: duration is over 15 minutes )
#
# For Picasa users without a Google+ registration the photo size limit is
# 800x800. To support these users too, you can specify the max. photo dimension
# and video duration for the unlimited storage pool as second and third
# parameters of this script.
#
# Version:       1.0
#
# Author:        muzso, 2012.02.25 (http://muzso.hu/)
# License:       GPLv2
#

import sys
import xml.dom.minidom
import urllib2

DIM_LIMIT = 2048
DUR_LIMIT = 900

def getText(nodelist):
    ret = ""
    for node in nodelist.childNodes:
        if node.nodeType == xml.dom.Node.TEXT_NODE:
            ret += node.data
    return ret.encode("utf-8")

######## Main Application ##########
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # PicasaWeb username is expected
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.stderr.write("usage: %s <Google username> [max_photo_dimension [max_video_duration]]\n" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)

    if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
        try:
            DIM_LIMIT = int(sys.argv[2])
        except ValueError:
            sys.stderr.write("Failed to convert \"%s\" to a number. The second parameter should be an integer specifying the maximum dimensions of photos counted into free storage.\n" % sys.argv[2])
            sys.exit(2)

        if len(sys.argv) >= 4:
            try:
                DUR_LIMIT = int(sys.argv[3])
            except ValueError:
                sys.stderr.write("The third parameter should be an integer specifying the maximum duration of videos counted into free storage.\n")
                sys.exit(3)

    print "Max. photo dimension (over which photos will be listed): %s" % DIM_LIMIT
    print "Max. video duration (over which videos will be listed): %s" % DUR_LIMIT

    baseurl = "http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/";

    url = baseurl + sys.argv[1]
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(resp)
    albums = dom.getElementsByTagName("entry")
    print "Found %s albums" % albums.length

    # replace username with id in the url
    url = baseurl + getText(dom.getElementsByTagName("gphoto:user")[0])

    tpiccount = 0
    tpicsize = 0
    tvidcount = 0
    tvidsize = 0

    for album in albums:
        albumid = getText(album.getElementsByTagName("gphoto:id")[0])
        albumname = getText(album.getElementsByTagName("title")[0])

        aurl = url + "/albumid/" + albumid
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(aurl)
        dom2 = xml.dom.minidom.parse(resp)

        entries = dom2.getElementsByTagName("entry")

        print "Processing album \"%s\" (has %s elements) ..." % (albumname, entries.length)

        piccount = 0
        picsize = 0
        vidcount = 0
        vidsize = 0

        for entry in entries:
            video = entry.getElementsByTagName("gphoto:originalvideo")
            if video.length > 0:
                dur = video[0].getAttribute("duration")
                if (dur != ""):
                    try:
                        dur = int(dur)
                        if dur > DUR_LIMIT:
                            vidcount += 1

                            size = getText(entry.getElementsByTagName("gphoto:size")[0])
                            try:
                                size = int(size)
                                vidsize += size
                            except ValueError:
                                sys.stderr.write("    \"%s\": failed to convert video size \"%s\" to a number\n" % (getText(entry.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]), size))
                                size = -1

                            print "  \"%s\": video duration = %s, size = %s" % (getText(entry.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]), dur, size)
                    except ValueError:
                        sys.stderr.write("    \"%s\": failed to convert video duration \"%s\" to a number\n" % (getText(entry.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]), dur))
            else:
                width = getText(entry.getElementsByTagName("gphoto:width")[0])
                try:
                    width = int(width)
                except ValueError:
                    sys.stderr.write("    \"%s\": failed to convert photo width \"%s\" to a number\n" % (getText(entry.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]), width))
                    width = -1

                height = getText(entry.getElementsByTagName("gphoto:height")[0])
                try:
                    height = int(height)
                except ValueError:
                    sys.stderr.write("    \"%s\": failed to convert photo height \"%s\" to a number\n" % (getText(entry.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]), height))
                    height = -1

                if width > DIM_LIMIT or height > DIM_LIMIT:
                    piccount += 1

                    size = getText(entry.getElementsByTagName("gphoto:size")[0])
                    try:
                        size = int(size)
                        picsize += size
                    except ValueError:
                        sys.stderr.write("    \"%s\": failed to convert size \"%s\" to a number\n" % (getText(entry.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]), size))
                        size = -1

                    print "  \"%s\": photo width = %s, height = %s, size = %s" % (getText(entry.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]), width, height, size)

            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stderr.flush()

        if piccount > 0:
            print "  Number and size of photos over the limit in \"%s\": %s (%s bytes)" % (albumname, piccount, picsize)
        if vidcount > 0:
            print "  Number and size of videos over the limit in \"%s\": %s (%s bytes)" % (albumname, vidcount, vidsize)

        tpiccount += piccount
        tpicsize += picsize
        tvidcount += vidcount
        tvidsize += vidsize

    if tpiccount > 0 or tvidcount > 0:
        if tpiccount > 0:
            print "Number and total size of photos with a dimension that is over the specified limit: %s (%s bytes)" % (tpiccount, tpicsize)
        if tvidcount > 0:
            print "Number and total size of videos with a duration that is over the specified limit: %s (%s bytes)" % (tvidcount, tvidsize)
    else:
        print "No photos or videos were found with a width, height or duration over the specidied limits."
```

Comment: Were you able to use the script? I have a similar problem and would like to check the size of photos and videos (all private). Would you recommend this Python script? How best should I run it (never having used Python?)